# Container of template class with automatic conversion problem

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors

I have the following code:

```
#include <vector>

template<int Wt = 0>
class fixed {
public:
 explicit fixed(double val = 0) {
  operator=(val);
 }

 ~fixed(){}

 operator double() const {
  return v_;
 }

 double operator =(const double &d){
  if (d>Wt)
   v_ = Wt;
  else
   v_ = d;
  return v_;
 }

private:
 double v_;
};

int main(){
 fixed<5> x;
   std::vector<fixed<6> > v(5);
 //std::vector<fixed<6> > v(5,0);
 //fixed<6> y;
 //v[0] = 0;
 x = x*v[0];
}
```

Compiling in VS 2005 express and 2010 express gives the following error:

> error C2676: binary '*' : 'fixed'
>   does not define this operator or a
>   conversion to a type acceptable to the
>   predefined operator

If I uncomment any of the three lines in the main (commenting the extra vector), it will compile. If I use gcc it will compile. Can anybody give a hint to why this is?

The code is a simplified version of a larger project so the three solutions are unfortunately not options for me.

Answer (score 1):

It seems as a glitch in vc++. If I ADD a string

```
 x = x* (*&v[0]);
```

BEFORE the string

```
x = x*v[0];
```

(which produced the error) then the error disappears (I use vc 2010 express). GCC compiles this code w/o errors, but only after renaming class fixed to something else (otherwise it complains about ambiguity of this name, i don't know exactly why, maybe it also  appears in some gcc headers)

Comment: The environment I tried was Qt which uses gcc, but guess it doesn't have the same headers. I have reported the bug:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/637760/container-of-template-class-with-automatic-conversion-problem